# How to use a variable for the key in an object in Groovy?

Tags: dictionary, groovy

In ES6 you can do

```js
const var1 = 'variableName';
const object = {
  [var1] : 'value'
}
```

How to use a variable for the key in a map just like above, in Groovy?

Answer (score 1):

You use brackets round the key to inform groovy it's a variable

```
def object = [
    (var1): 'value'
]
```

Answer (score 0):

In groovy you can do the same as:

```
def var1 = 'variableName'
def object = [
    "$var1":'value'
]
```

Comment: You should be careful using groovy strings as keys for maps...  all sorts of fun can ensue

Comment: `[ ("$var1".toString()):'value' ]` :)